# MongoDB with Node.js says "Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cloud9

I'm using MongoDB with Node.js to create a little blog on Cloud9 IDE.

It's working fine on `localhost`. But when I uploaded it to C9, I got this problem:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongolass/lib/query.js:54
       this[plugin.name] = (...args) => {
                            ^^^
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Use nvm to change  node version on c9

Answer (score 1):

the version of Node.js you are using on C9 doesn't support the `...args` rest params syntax.

either downgrade your local node version, or upgrade the c9 version to the same as you are using on your local box.